# How do I convert an XML field with more than 8000 characters into a string?

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server column of type `XML` containing some records with more than 8000 characters.

I would like to convert this column into a `varchar`.

I am not concerned about truncation (the first 8000 characters is fine).

However, whenever I try `CONVERT(varchar(8000), Content)` I get an error:

> Target string size is too small to represent the XML instance

When I try `CONVERT(varchar(MAX), Content)` I get an error:

> String or binary data would be truncated

When I try `CONVERT(varchar(20000), Content)` I get an error:

> The size (20000) given to the type 'varchar' exceeds the maximum allowed for any data type (8000)

When I try `CONVERT(text, Content)` I get an error:

> Explicit conversion from data type xml to text is not allowed

Is there a workaround?

Comment: Casting to `varchar(max)` should work just fine. [Like this does.](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/75495).

Comment: Maybe it's configuration then.. I certainly get an error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Cast to `varchar(max)` should work just fine. You probably have an issue elsewhere. You would get that error if you try to insert/update a column with datatype `varchar(8000)`.

Comment: Issue was passing it to a `hashbytes` function which has an 8000 limit max :-)

Comment: Wrote up the particular use-case I was having here: http://mattmitchell.com.au/detecting-duplicate-xml-data-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 2):

The issue that you are running into has to do with attempting to convert the `XML` into `VARCHAR`. I have run into a similar issue before when trying to convert an `XML` string that is much smaller than yours into `NVARCHAR`. Switching from a `CONVERT` to a `CAST` should solve your problem. As far as the size, you are better off just setting it to `MAX`.

Answer (score 1):

I have never had this particular need, but another way I would try would be:

```
SUBSTRING(CAST(Content AS VARCHAR), 1, 8000)
```

This will obviously truncate the content, so you should be aware of that if that's not appropriate for your use case.

Comment: This will truncate the string, which is probably not the desired result.

Comment: Unfortunately not, it tries to cast before you have a chance to substring it > `Target string size is too small to represent the XML instance`

Comment: Ignore my comment, this would probably work although the substring is unnecessary.